# How to call a Powershell script in Classic ASP file

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script which creates a job folder in an Isilon share whenever it is invoked. However, I need to run this using a Classic ASP file.

So every time I click on button, it should take the job number input text value as argument and then call the powershell script and pass the argument to the script and execute the powershell script.

How to achieve this?

**Edit**

In the ASP file at present we have this snippet which calls a vbscript to create a folder. However, this ASP page works only in Internet Explorer. In order to make it compatible with Chrome and edge browser we need to replace the vbscript with powershell. We have the powershell script ready but we are not sure how to add it to the ASP file.

```
<script language="vbscript" runat="server">
</script>
<html>
<head>
<title>CSJobs Job Creation Page</title>
</head>
<body>

    <% if Request.Form("foldernumber") = "" then
        Response.Write("<h2>This is a page to create a new Folder</h2>")
       else
        set objshell = Server.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
        strTemp = "cmd /c cscript C:\APPS\NewJob\CSJobsCreate.vbs " & Request.Form("foldernumber")
        objshell.Run strTemp, 0, True
        Response.Write(Request.Form("foldernumber") & " has been created.")
       end if
    %>

<Form action "NewJob.asp" METHOD="POST">
<Input name="foldernumber">
<Input Type="submit" value="Create">
</Form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

One issue is `Powershell` is built on `.NET framework`, so I wonder, what you are doing in `Powershell` that perhaps `ASP Classic` can handle itself?  ASP Classic has a File Handler system that might be able to do what you need within ASP its self, unless you are dealing with Services or something a bit more advanced.  If you are copying files, or creating text files generated from data, you might be able to just use ASP.  If you are trying to do a "NET STOP/START" command, I'd love to hear a way to do that.  For things that I can't do in ASP Classic but must, I use MYSQL's built in Event Scheduler or in crude situations MS Task Scheduler (shudder).

You can use the file system in ASP to create folders, here is a simple line of code to do that:

```
dim newfolder
newfolder = Request.Form("foldernumber")
set fileobj=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If  Not fileobj.FolderExists("c:\"& newfolder & "\") Then      
  fileobj.CreateFolder ("c:\"& newfolder & "\")
End If
```

Comment: Found this info just now, which reminded me that when ASP Classic can't do something, there might be a commercial "add-on" module you can get.  I use one to generate PDF files from databases using ASP classic.  This info below has not been tested but posting it here in case it helps you. 

f the shell scripts are normally run on a telnet session then you could screen scrape and parse the responses. There are commercial COM components out there such as the Dart telnet library: http://www.dart.com/pttel.aspx that would let you do this.

Comment: I don't know if you noticed the edit, but I added some code to create a folder based off of a form supplied variable.  Keep in note, any form provided variable should be validated before using it in your code to avoid exploits.  I can offer some info on that if you like after we sort this if you like, but if its all in shop stuff you should be fine, but if you allow your script to have web access, or if its just localmachine make sure you trust your users.

Comment: Sorry. But we need to execute the functionality using powershell script only. Plus, the folder is being created in an domain specific isilon share. This ASP page is deployed on a server. Depending on whether its a test or production server URL, folder will be created in appropriate isilon share. The script is also applying some necessary permissions on the newly created folder.

Comment: You can assign file permissions but not user permissions, although you can tie in domain authentication to your ASP scripts through IIS settings.  But yeah if the server that is running the asp script isn't the same server location as the where the folder needs to be created then this might not work.  And I'm unsure about setting user permissions with ASP, although my spidey sense tells me sometimes these sorts of things are solved with commercial ASP script add on modules.   But if you are needing Isilon to do it, then I'm not sure if it has a way to pass the variable or not.